# How to find the outer length from Circle mid point

Tags: c#, math, data-structures, geometry

How to find the length from the center point of circle till the rectangles border based on the angle from Circle midpoint..

I try AC^2 =√AB^2 - BC^2

Sample Image

[image]

Comment: This should really be posted on [Math.StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Draw a line starting from the circle's center, moving right until it intersects the rectangle. You now have a right triangle whose legs have length (rect_height - radius) and (rect_width - radius). You can find the length of the yellow line by calculating the hypotenuse.

?  = sqrt((rect_height - radius)^2 + (rect_width - radius)^2)

Comment: This answer assumes that you already know the dimensions of the rectangle, and that the yellow line always intersects with the rectangle's corner. Let me know if either of these assumptions are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
Let the size of the square be S.
Let the radius of the circle be R
Where S > R

Let A be the angle in degrees, where 0 <= A <= 90
Let L be the required diagonal length.

Then if 0 <= A <= 45, L = (S-R)/Cos(A)
And if 45 < A <= 90, L = (S-R)/Sin(A)
```

If expressing this in C#, remember that `Math.Sin()` and `Math.Cos()` use radians, not degrees.

This is just an alternative to Kevin's approach using Pythagoras. Both approaches should of course give the same answers. :)